# Drilling/screwing into exterior metal door?

Tags: doors, exterior, metal

I am wondering about drilling/screwing into an exterior metal door.  I want to install a dart board & back board onto the back of my exterior door that leads into the garage.  My worries are as follows:
- Will this damage the integrity of the door (i.e. since this is probably a fire door, will this be a bad idea?)
- Will this cause the door to lose insulating value for the basement?
- What's inside these doors, will it be able to hold a dartboard mounted on plywood?

Thanks!
Sean

Comment: If you use screws just long enough to hold the plywood on, maybe a few extra screws that just penetrate it should not damage the structure, most of these doors are filled with mostly foam and some wood structure. If your screws go into the door two far they would conduct the heat to the plywood

Comment: Your local building/fire code *may* have something to say about drilling holes in a door separating a garage from living space,,,

Answer (score 1):

I would look in to magnets. I recently purchased a magnet and hook to hang a Christmas wreath. It was about $5. It is strong enough that the easiest way to remove it is to slide it off the edge. I checked Amazon has them rated for 8 lbs.

Answer (score 1):

A few screws will not compromise the structural integrity of the door. A few hundred wouldn't, either.

Insulation value will not be substantially altered. Most of that is in the foam, which will only lose a fraction of a percent in volume.

Any fire protection the door provides is intended to protect from the garage. It's unlikely that a few small holes on the interior will do anything to reduce such protection.

Use screws of sufficient diameter to provide solid grip. A #6 or #8 is too small. I'd go with short #10 or #12 screws, assuming at least 4. I'd also back the board with double-sided foam tape for additional support.